Invalid address 0x71db7cb5e0 passed to free: value not allocated
getting below error after calling free() function for filepaths (free(filePaths[i]);) just after running Android application with minSDK=22 or above. Everything is OK on minSDK=21

Invalid address 0x71db7cb5e0 passed to free: value not allocated
I just want to know what happens for Android with minSDK=22 or above. Are memory allocations different?

static inline void parse_proc_maps_to_fetch_path(char **filepaths);

JNIEXPORT jboolean JNICALL Java_io_github_inflationx_calligraphy_Calligraphy_CalligraphyInterceptor_detectFrida(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj) {

    char *filePaths[NUM_LIBS];

    globalEnv = env;
    parse_proc_maps_to_fetch_path(filePaths);
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_VERBOSE, APPNAME, "Libc[%x][%x][%x][%x][%x][%x]", __NR_openat,
                        __NR_lseek, __NR_read, __NR_close, __NR_readlinkat, __NR_nanosleep);
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_LIBS; i++) {
        fetch_checksum_of_library(filePaths[i], &elfSectionArr[i]);
        if (filePaths[i] != NULL)
            free(filePaths[i]);
    }
    bool result = false;
    pthread_t t;
    pthread_create(&t, NULL, (void *) detect_frida_loop, &result);
    return result;
}

__attribute__((always_inline))
static inline void parse_proc_maps_to_fetch_path(char **filepaths) {
    int fd = 0;
    char map[MAX_LINE];
    int counter = 0;
    if ((fd = my_openat(AT_FDCWD, PROC_MAPS, O_RDONLY | O_CLOEXEC, 0)) != 0) {

        while ((read_one_line(fd, map, MAX_LINE)) > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < NUM_LIBS; i++) {
                if (my_strstr(map, libstocheck[i]) != NULL) {
                    char tmp[MAX_LENGTH] = "";
                    char path[MAX_LENGTH] = "";
                    char buf[5] = "";
                    sscanf(map, "%s %s %s %s %s %s", tmp, buf, tmp, tmp, tmp, path);
                    if (buf[2] == 'x') {
                        size_t size = my_strlen(path) + 1;
                        filepaths[i] = malloc(size);
                        my_strlcpy(filepaths[i], path, size);
                        counter++;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (counter == NUM_LIBS)
                break;
        }
        my_close(fd);
    }
}


globalEnv = env;?  You can not cache a JNIEnv *env value.

globalEnv has no usage

provided code is the only usage ( read and write ) of filepaths

Maybe unrelated, but what is my_openat? What does it return if it fails? Does it return -1? Then you'll continue, and will use the (invalid) file descriptor -1. Since reading from the file will then fail, you will end the function with all elements of filepaths being uninitialized and with indeterminate values.

Related to the above problem, what happens if not all elements of filepaths are initialized? If the loops ends before counter == NUM_LIBS?

by putting logs after filepaths[i] = malloc(size); I realized that malloc function is called.

@nima For all elements?

(fd = my_openat(AT_FDCWD, PROC_MAPS, O_RDONLY | O_CLOEXEC, 0)) != 0 is also wrong.  First, don't cram that into the if - that's a horrible bug-prone way to write code that was idiomatic when code was entered on punch cards and lead was put into gasoline.  Second: 0 is a valid file descriptor so can't be used to indicate an error.

In Java_io_github_inflationx_calligraphy_Calligraphy_CalligraphyInterceptor_detectFrida, you define filePaths, leaving the values in the array uninitialized:
char *filePaths[NUM_LIBS];

In parse_proc_maps_to_fetch_path, you then only assign values to filepaths[i] if some condition is true, leaving those elements uninitialized otherwise.
You seem to be assuming that the elements of filePaths will be NULL be default, which is not the case for a local variable in a function. The elements of filePaths don't have defined values.
To fix this, you could initialize filePaths:
char *filePaths[NUM_LIBS] = { 0 };

You could alternatively structure parse_proc_maps_to_fetch_path in such a way that all elements of filePaths are always assigned values (NULL when you aren't assigning a pointer to a meaningful string). This may be the better option if parse_proc_maps_to_fetch_path is intended to "produce" the array in its entirety.
